# Find the index of the last occurrence of a letter in a string

Tags: python

For example "l" in "hello" should return 3.

```
search = input()
s = input()
start=0

for idx, letter in enumerate(s):
    if letter == search:
        print (idx)
```

Currently I have written this which will print 2 and 3, but is it possible to get this to just print 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `rfind()` method. Like this:

```
search = input() #if user input is l
s = input() #and user input is hello
print (s.rfind(search)) #returns 3
```

It spits out the last index of `search` in `s`

Comment: would love to hear the downvoters reason. This seems like the perfect solution.

Comment: @PaulRooney exactly my thoughts.

Comment: every now and again you get someone that comes in and just sticks a DV on all the answers. Can't do much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Store and update the index and only print it at the end:

```
s = "hello"
search = 'l'

last_found = None
for idx, letter in enumerate(s):
    if letter == search:
        last_found = idx
print (last_found)
```

or loop in reverse order:

```
for idx in range(len(s)-1,-1,-1):
    if s[idx] == search:
        break
print (idx)
```

Comment: Why are you using the "None" as a string?

Comment: Yep typo (although not a big deal :)

Comment: @BOi "too much" work is only an opinion. This is trying to stick to and add on OP's original code. Using builtin function is certainly a good idea but also doesn't teach you much...

Comment: @Julien that's like letting the OP add and subtract without using + and - operators and instead using bits. Why would you make someone learn that when there is a easier way to do it.

Comment: That is not a good analogy, there is a very good reason to learn bitwise operations.

Comment: Both answers are technically correct. So why not just let the OP decide. Objectively `rfind` is the faster and more idomatic solution, but this is not a wrong answer.

Comment: @BOi that's a silly argument. Have you never re-implemented a quicksort or what not just for the sake of learning?

Comment: @PaulRooney looks like OP has no clue how to accept an answer :)

Comment: @Julien the OP doesn't know that there is a quicker solution. If he/she had said that she was trying to reimplement the algorithm, then surely add on to the code. But, my argument is why point OP in that direction if there are easier ways to do it and he/she is not aware of this.